# Why Gmail chat appears when the screen is locked?

Tags: 11.10, laptop, gmail

When I lock the screen, Gmail chat appears at the bottom of the screen just like when it's unlocked. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely sounds like a bug.

I would suggest using Empathy for chatting instead of the web interface, because I have no experienced this problem with Empathy (or with the web interface for that matter). You can report the bug against the `gnome-screensaver` package.

You can also mark it as affecting `chromium-browser` (optionally), because imo Chromium should not display anything when the screensaver or screenlock is active.

Comment: Can we close this as one of thoze bugz?!

Comment: You should only report this bug against `chromium-browser` if the problem happens in the Chromium web browser... Otherwise, it should be reported against the package for whatever browser or application it occurred in.

Comment: @jrg I don't think this question should be closed as a bug. It is *not* a bug; it is a question about *whether or not* a particular behavior would be considered to be a bug.

Comment: @EliahKagan I know for a fact (don't ask how) that it occurs in Chromium only.

Comment: @RolandTaylor I presume you've experienced the bug. Do you know if it's already been reported?

Comment: @Explorer It occurs to me that even if it is happening in Chromium, the *bug* might not be in Chromium. It shouldn't be up to the application to behave properly in order for its UI elements not to pop up on top of a locked screen. So maybe the bug is really in `gnome-screensaver`. I'd suggest reporting it against one or the other of `chromium-browser` (assuming that really is the application creating the UI elements in question) or `gnome-screensaver`, and then adding a bug task for the other one (use `Also affects distribution` on the bug page and select Ubuntu and the other package).

Comment: @Eliah That is also true. If you check the chat room you will see that I first suspected it was gnome-screensaver, but we eventually settled on it being Chromium.

Comment: @RolandTaylor I can't tell from reading [the chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201) how it was decided that it was not a bug in gnome-screensaver, but I presume there was a reason for it...anyway, the task can always be changed later or a new task can be added. The most important thing is that the bug be reported, especially since, as [George](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1345/george-edison) said (I paraphrase), it's a security bug as well as a usability bug.

Comment: @EliahKagan I told you in a previous comment "don't ask how" :). Let's just say we communicate outside of AU - and I determined it was Chromium from our conversation.

Comment: @RolandTaylor I don't want to get into a pedantic squabble here in the comments, but you told me not to ask how you knew it only happened in Chromium (and I didn't). Even if it only happens in Chromium, that doesn't mean it's not a bug in `gnome-screensaver`. Even if it happens with multiple screensavers, it doesn't mean it's not a bug in multiple screensavers... It's fine that you're not explaining that here on AskUbuntu, and I am not asking you to. But the reasoning for this being a bug in Chromium and not `gnome-screensaver` does need to be explained in the bug report itself on Launchpad.

Comment: @EliahKagan After some thought you might be right - which means my original assumption (as you would have seen in chat) was correct :P... I'll edit my answer :)

Thanks!

Comment: http://community.kde.org/KWin/Screenlocker , though about KDE, indicates that screen locking is not as simple as one might think.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When the screen is locked, users will reasonably assume that potentially private information that might be displayed on the screen will *not* be displayed until and unless the screen is unlocked. Assuming that this is from the Gmail web-based interface, this is a bug in your web browser (which interprets the Javascript in the Gmail and creates the chat "windowlets" as interface elements). On the other hand, if you are seeing chat windows or tabs from a standalone instant messaging applications like Empathy or Pidgin, then it is a bug in that application.

I recommend [reporting this bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Sorry if I accepted the other answer, I was looking for the package to report the bug.

Comment: @Explorer No problem. But `chromium-browser` is only the correct package if the problem is occurring in the Chromium web browser. Otherwise, that is the wrong package.